# MySQL timestamp column - auto update when last ACCESSED (not modified)

Tags: mysql

So I have timestamp column in table that I wanted to update every time that row is accessed, including INSERT, SELECT & UPDATE statements. 
(Note that not just when the row is modified)

Is there built-in feature for MySQL to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature that does this! In MySQL they are called [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). With Triggers you can run additional MySQL code when performing an action (i.e.: when INSERTING, SELECTING, UPDATING, DELETING, etc. a table).

Comment: According to the docs you linked, triggers can be created for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE. SELECT is not an option.